# Resolution Manipulation for Template Matching in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, pdf, image-processing, resolution

I am trying to use template matching to find an equation inside a given pdf document that is generated from LaTeX. When I use the code over [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html), I get only a very good matching when I crop the picture from the original page (converted to jpeg or png), however when I compile the equation code separately and generate an jpg/png output of it the matching goes wrong tremendously.

I believe the reason is relevant to the resolution, but since I am an amateur in this field, I cannot reasonably make the jpg generated out of standalone equation to have the same pixel structure of the jpg for the whole page. Here is the code that is copied (more or less) from the above-mentioned website of OpenCV, which is an implementation for python:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread('location of the original image', 0)
img2 = img.copy()
template = cv2.imread('location of the patch I look for',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

# All the 6 methods for comparison in a list
methods = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_CCORR',
            'cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']

method = eval(methods[0])

# Apply template Matching
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
# If the method is TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, take minimum
if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
    top_left = min_loc
else:
    top_left = max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
print top_left, bottom_right

img = Image.open('location of the original image')

#cropping the original image with the found coordinates to make a qualitative comparison
cropped = img.crop((top_left[0], top_left[1], bottom_right[0], bottom_right[1]))
cropped.save('location to save the cropped image using the coordinates found by template matching')
```

Here is a sample page that I look for the first equation:
[image]

The code to generate a specific standalone equation is as follows:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}\begin{align*}
(\mu_1+\mu_2)(\emptyset) = \mu_1(\emptyset) + \mu_2(\emptyset) = 0 + 0 =0
\label{eq_0}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Which I compile and later trim the white space around the equation either using [pdfcrop](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/) or using .image() method in [PythonMagick](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonMagick). Template matching generated with this trimmed output on the original page does not give a reasonable result. Here is the trimmed/converted output using pdfcrop/Mac's Preview.app:

[image].

Cropping directly the equation from the above page works perfectly. I would appreciate some explanation and help.

***EDIT***:
I also found the following which uses template matching by bruteforcing different possible scales:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/

However since I am willing to process as many as 1000 of documents, this seems a very slow method to go for. Plus I imagine there should be a more logical way of handling it, by somehow finding the relevant scales.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of template matching you could use [features](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html#matcher), i.e. keypoints with descriptors. They are scale- invariant, so you do not need to iterate over different scaled versions of the image.

The python example [find_obj.py](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/find_obj.py)
 provieded with OpenCV works with ORB features for your given example.

```
python find_obj.py --feature=brisk rB4Yy_big.jpg ZjBAA.jpg
```

[image: result]

Note that I did not use the cropped version of the formula to search for, but a version with some white pixels around it, so the keypoint detection can work correctly. There needs to be some space around it, because keypoints have to be completely inside the image. Otherwise the descriptors can not be calculated.

[image: padded formula]

The big image is the original from your post.

One additional remark: You will always get *some* matches. If the formula image you are searching for is not present in the big images, the matches will be nonsensical. If you need to sort out these false positives, you have the following options:

- Check if the average distance of the resulting [DMatch](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#dmatch)es is small enough.
- Check if the [transformation matrix](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html#feature-homography) can be calculated.

---

**Edit**: Since you asked for it, here is a version that draws the bounding box around the found formula instead of the matches:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Python 2/3 compatibility
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import cv2

def init_feature():
    detector = cv2.BRISK_create()
    norm = cv2.NORM_HAMMING
    matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(norm)
    return detector, matcher

def filter_matches(kp1, kp2, matches, ratio = 0.75):
    mkp1, mkp2 = [], []
    for m in matches:
        if len(m) == 2 and m[0].distance < m[1].distance * ratio:
            m = m[0]
            mkp1.append( kp1[m.queryIdx] )
            mkp2.append( kp2[m.trainIdx] )
    p1 = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in mkp1])
    p2 = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in mkp2])
    kp_pairs = zip(mkp1, mkp2)
    return p1, p2, kp_pairs

def explore_match(win, img1, img2, kp_pairs, status = None, H = None):
    h1, w1 = img1.shape[:2]
    h2, w2 = img2.shape[:2]
    vis = np.zeros((max(h1, h2), w1+w2), np.uint8)
    vis[:h1, :w1] = img1
    vis[:h2, w1:w1+w2] = img2
    vis = cv2.cvtColor(vis, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    if H is not None:
        corners = np.float32([[0, 0], [w1, 0], [w1, h1], [0, h1]])
        corners = np.int32( cv2.perspectiveTransform(corners.reshape(1, -1, 2), H).reshape(-1, 2) + (w1, 0) )
        cv2.polylines(vis, [corners], True, (0, 0, 255))

    cv2.imshow(win, vis)
    return vis

if __name__ == '__main__':

    img1 = cv2.imread('rB4Yy_big.jpg' , 0)
    img2 = cv2.imread('ZjBAA.jpg', 0)
    detector, matcher = init_feature()

    kp1, desc1 = detector.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
    kp2, desc2 = detector.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

    raw_matches = matcher.knnMatch(desc1, trainDescriptors = desc2, k = 2)
    p1, p2, kp_pairs = filter_matches(kp1, kp2, raw_matches)
    if len(p1) >= 4:
        H, status = cv2.findHomography(p1, p2, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
        print('%d / %d  inliers/matched' % (np.sum(status), len(status)))
        vis = explore_match('find_obj', img1, img2, kp_pairs, status, H)
        cv2.waitKey()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    else:
        print('%d matches found, not enough for homography estimation' % len(p1))
```

[image: bounding box]

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed reply. I wasn't able to run the find_obj.py code as it needs the package common and I couldn't find it. But does this find_obj provide the coordinates around the box which contains the smaller picture? That is the most important thing for me.

Comment: @Cupitor The example itself does not put a box around it. But since you have the box around the formula-only image (just the image boundaries) and you have the corresponding points in the large image, you can easily get the box in the large image by calculating the transformation matrix determined by the keypoint matches and then warping the box.

Comment: @Cupitor The common package is also in the python example directory of OpenCV. But I made a modified stand-alone version of `find_obj.py` that  draws the bounding box around the found formula in red. I added the code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with template matching is that it only works in very controlled environments. Meaning that it will work perfectly if you take the template from the actual image, but it won't work if the resolution is different or even if the image is a little bit turned.

I would suggest you finding another algorithm more suitable for this problem. In [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/text.html) you can find some specific algorithms for your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Since the there is absolutely no change my picture from angular point of view, there seems to me there should be a logic to correct it. I should add that I was not able to find something else in OpenCV which is able to return the exact coordinates of the match. It is mostly feature matching!